# SQL Two fields from tables of unassociated data into the same field?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, field

I am trying to do this is SQL:

```
-------------------------------
Table A
-------------------------------
ID | Title
1  | Something Groovy
2  | Something Else

-------------------------------
Table B
-------------------------------
ID | Title
1  | Something Different
2  | Something More
```

**Awesome Select Statement**

```
-------------------------------
Both in one field
-------------------------------
Title
Something Groovy
Something Else
Something Different
Something More
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to obtain the union of two selects.  If you want to eliminate duplicates, use simply `UNION`.

```
SELECT Title FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Title FROM TableB
```

Comment: FYI the effect of the "ALL" clause is to keep duplicates, so that your result will have those duplicates if they were in both sets.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple union:

```
Select title from TableA

UNION

Select title from TableB
```

Note that any items that are identical will be eliminated.